# MS-Access and Sharepoint external data sources importing problem

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access-2010

me and my colleagues we are sharing folders on SharePoint so everyone can see common folder with an address like "C:\Users" & username & "\...\...\" on his pc.

we would like to use a db access linking external data sources adding csv file form a common SharePoint folder but as you can imagine if i link the data source all my colleagues cannot open that folder because the linking address reports my username.

on access what i did to import a new data source linking the new source is :
external data > new data source > from file > text file

but is seems is not possible to link a sharepoint folder pointing to it via http... any other solutions?